# how to pass this page as object to the next page in pom?

Tags: java, selenium, testng, pageobjects

How to pass this login page as object to the next page(i.e, dashboard page) in page object model?

I've tired return statement but it is not working.

```
public class LoginPage {
    WebDriver driver;

    public void LPage(WebDriver driver) {

        this.driver=driver;
    }

    By UserName = By.id("username");
    By Password = By.id("pass");
    By Login = By.xpath("//*[@type='submit']");

    public WebElement un() {
        return driver.findElement(UserName);
    }

    public WebElement pwd() {
        return driver.findElement(Password);
    }

    public WebElement submit() {
         driver.findElement(Login).click();
        return submit();
    }
}
```

I need to return this LoginPage as an object to DashBoard class so there will be a continuity flow of program after login.

Comment: The [tag:pom.xml] tag is for the [Maven Project Object Model](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-pom.html). It sounds like you're talking about some other kind of `pom.xml` here?

Comment: @DanielPryden Page Object Model

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `submit()` function you are returning the `submit()` function but its return type is `WebElement`.

If you are trying to pass the handle to the next page you have to do return that type of object and pass the driver handle.

**Passing another page object:**

Update your `submit()` method in `LoginPage` to this:

```java
public DashboardPage submit(){
    driver.findElement(Login).click();
    return new DashboardPage(driver);
}
```

In the test, call it like this:

```java
@Test
public void test(){
    Webdriver driver = new Chromedriver();//For expample I'm using Chromedriver
    driver.get("YourTestAppilcationURL");
    LoginPage loginPage = new LoginPage(driver);
    loginPage.un.sendKeys("username");
    loginPage.pwd.sendKeys("password");
    DashboardPage dashboardPage = loginPage.submit();
//Now perform tasks in the dashboardPage
}
```

You can read about it in the [Selenium wiki](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/PageObjects)

---

---

In my opinion, it is better to not pass another page object from a page object action class.
Try to initiate the page objects in your test and use it from there.

To do that just don't return the DashboardPage object from the submit method.

```java
public void submit(){
    driver.findElement(Login).click();
```

Then use that in the test:

```
@Test
public void loginTest(Webdriver driver){
    LoginPage loginPage = new LoginPage(driver);
    DashboardPage dashboardPage = new DashboardPage(driver);
    loginPage.submit();
    Assert.AssertTrue(dashboardPage.isLoaded());
}
```

Comment: @S Ahmed i tried the above method, but it's showing error in the last line of the code "return new DashboardPage(driver); " The constructor DashboardPage(WebDriver) is undefined

Comment: @ghostdeathrider Sorry that it was not clear enough for you to understand. Only the first part would return another page object but I was mentioning my preferred way in the second part.  I have edited the answer. Now it has the method and test for both ways.